# Sorting structs alphabetically

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct AuthorRecord {
    char *textTitle;
    int NumberOfWords;
    long Download;
    struct AuthorRecord *next;
};
typedef struct AuthorRecord *AuthorRecordType;

typedef struct {
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int idNumber;
    AuthorRecordType text;
} AuthorType;

struct MemberNodeStruct {
    AuthorType *anAuthor;
    struct MemberNodeStruct *next;
};
typedef struct MemberNodeStruct *MemberNodeType;


AuthorRecordType createBook(){
/*Creates a new AuthorRecord and returns the pointer to it*/
    AuthorRecordType book = (AuthorRecordType)malloc(sizeof(AuthorRecordType));
    if(book==NULL) printf("cannot allocate memory for Book");
    book->next=NULL;
    return book;
}

AuthorType *createAuthor(){
/*Creates a new AuthorType and returns the pointer to it*/
    AuthorType  *p;
    p=(AuthorType*)malloc(sizeof(AuthorType));
    if(p==NULL) printf("cannot allocate memory for Author");
    return p;
}

MemberNodeType createMember(){
/*Creates a new MemberNode and returns the pointer to it*/
    MemberNodeType p;
    p=(MemberNodeType)malloc(sizeof(MemberNodeType));
    if(p==NULL) printf("cannot allocate memory for Member");
    p->anAuthor=createAuthor();
    p->next=NULL;
    return p;
}


void writeAuthor(MemberNodeType p){
/*Writes the info of an Author where the pointer p points*/
    scanf("%s%s%d", p->anAuthor->firstName, p->anAuthor->lastName, &p->anAuthor->idNumber);
    return;
}

void writeBook(AuthorRecordType p){
/*Writes the info of a Book where the pointer p points*/
    fgets (p->textTitle, 64, stdin);
    scanf("%ld", &p->Download);
    return;
}

void printAuthor(MemberNodeType p){
/*Prints the info of the Author where the pointer p points*/
    printf("%s %s %d\n", p->anAuthor->firstName,p->anAuthor->lastName, p->anAuthor->idNumber);
    return;
}
void printBook(AuthorRecordType p){
/*points the info of the Book where the pointer p points*/
    printf("%s %ld\n", p->textTitle, p->Download);
    return;
}



MemberNodeType writethelists(){
/*Fills the list with the given data*/
    int NumberofAuthors, NumberofBooks=0 ,i, j;
    MemberNodeType head=NULL, curr=NULL;
    AuthorRecordType book;
    printf("type number of authors \n");
    scanf("%d", &NumberofAuthors);

    for (i=0; i<NumberofAuthors; i++){
        printf("getting into author loop \n");
        if (head==NULL) {
            printf("creating new member \n");
            head=curr=createMember();
        }
        else{
            printf("creating additional member \n");
            curr=curr->next=createMember();
        }
        printf("write author info \n");
        writeAuthor(curr);
        if (curr->anAuthor->lastName < curr->anAuthor)

        printf("type number of books \n");
        scanf("%d", &NumberofBooks);
        for (j=0; j<NumberofBooks; j++){
            printf("books loop");
            if (j==0){
                printf("creating new book for author\n");
                curr->anAuthor->text = book = createBook();
            }
            else{
                printf("creating additional book\n");
                book=book->next=createBook();
            }
            printf("write book info \n");
            writeBook(book);
        }
    }
return head;
}
```

It's supposed to take authors and their books into those structs. The thing that troubles me is sorting authors by their name. I have written the code a way that i don't think i can now sort them while inserting them. 
What's a nice way to sort them after inserting them?

Edit:
I know the code is incomplete. I am just writing functions right now which i will simply use in the main() later

Comment: The code supplied is incomplete.  Please edit the code to include a 'main()' function (where the program starts), and proposes how the above functions.

Comment: AuthorRecordType and MemberNodeType are pointers but AuthorType is not?

Comment: I get a little nervous when I see `head=curr=createMember()` in a function that is supposed to write the list auf authors, ie. that operates on the list in read-only mode. Pointers in such a function should either be pointers to existing nodes or `NULL`. You should only create Nodes when you insert new nodes in the list. I suggest you get that right before worrying about sorting.

Comment: @eznme MembernodeType and AuthorRecordType have a next section, meaning they need to have a pointer at them but an AuthorType can only be one in every MemberNode.

Comment: @user3697377 Yes but you will confuse them if you re-read your code 1 month from now because they are named so similarly. I suggest you either consistently make them all pointers or name them PAuthor for a pointer and StructAuthor for a struct for example.

Comment: if you add a back link to the member structure, you can easily sort them by, at each new member struct creation, search from head, looking for a authors name that is later alphabetically from what is in the new member struct,  then insert the new member struct just before the member struct with the later author name.

Comment: if the number of authors/members is small, say ~10 or less, then insertion sort would work very nicely.  as the number of entries get larger, a sync sort or qsort would be faster (and require a LOT more code).  As I suggested above, use a doubly linked list and sort at member struct creation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a category of sorting algorithms called [online algoritms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aOnline_sorts). They are most suitable in your case, as probably you will have to add elements to the list while keeping it sorted. If you are a beginner in this topic, I would suggest to start with insertion sort, as it is pretty simple.

If you want to get a performance boost, you can use a more efficient sorting algoritm to sort the initial list (like quicksort) and use an online sorting algorithm to keep it sorted as more elements come.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking us for a quick fix for this specific problem, and next time you maybe come again with a large hierarchy of structs, again asking us to do something to it.

Here's something that may be more valuable: Try to work incrementally. First make a main-function and a short linked list of structs that each only contain an integer. Then write a function that sorts that linked list.

That way you dont need to worry about all the stuff about authors and books and strings and allocation and printing. When that function works *then* you can change it to authors etc.